# Microsoft Reporting with Collection as DataSource

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I'm working with **MS Reporting Services**. The underlying datasource is

`IEnumerable<MyObject>`, I'm not using DataSets.

Every `MyObject` has properties and some other `IEnumerable` collections.
In the report I want to display all the properties from `MyObject` and
the collections lists too.
I didn't know how to display this inner collections, so I've made a **SubReport** to which I passed the `MyObject`.Id so that the SubReport could retrieve the object by himself and Build a the DataSource for these inner collections.
I do this in this event.

```
myReportViewer.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(LocalReport_SubreportProcessing);

private void LocalReport_SubreportProcessing(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
{
    int id;
    if (e.Parameters.Count > 0 && int.TryParse(e.Parameters[0].Values[0], out id))
    {
        MyObject current = myObjects.Where(x => x.MyObject.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

        InnerListBindingSource.DataSource = current.InnerCollection;
        e.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource(
            "MyInnerCollectionDataSource", InnerListBindingSource));
    }
}
```

But there is always "The SubReport could not be shown" in my Master Report.
(Master report - subreport are correctly binded)

Any Idea why? Or how to resolve this in a more elegant way ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.

So I went to this solution and it's working:

```
private IEnumerable<MyObject> myObjects;

public ReportViewerForm(IEnumerable<MyObject> myObjects)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.myObjects = myObjects;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

    ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();            

    reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

    reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = @"SomePath." + "Report1.rdlc";
    /*reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"SomePath\Report1.rdlc"; */

    reportViewer.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing +=
                new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(SubreportProcessingEventHandler);            

    reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(
       new ReportDataSource("MyDataSource", myObjects));

    reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new List<ReportParameter> 
    {
        new ReportParameter("param1", ..WhatEver..),
        ...
    }); 

    reportViewer.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(reportViewer);

    reportViewer.RefreshReport();
}

void SubreportProcessingEventHandler(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
{          
    /* For example ID parsing.. when you have it defined in .rdlc file.. */
    int id;
    if (e.Parameters.Count > 0 && int.TryParse(e.Parameters[0].Values[0], out id))
    {   
        MyObject current = myObjects.Where(x => x.MyObject.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

        e.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource(
            "InnerListDataSource", current.InnerList));              
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have a structure that resembles a table. So why don't you take a DataTable? ReportingServices offers easy access to those.
Or did I get you wrong there?

Comment: This Collection is retrieved from ObjectRelational Mapper, and it contains ForeignKey objects, Foreign Collections etc. I'd have to rebuild it do the DataTable.. Do you think that's a good approach?

Comment: Honestly: I don't know. But a DataSet/DataTable is usually a good choice to map to from a relational data source. DataSet offers most functionality a DataBase does, and a table is the basic structure of a relational datasource. I only worked with a Table until now, so I guess that could also be the reason why I'd choose them again. :)

Comment: I guess it depends how hard it is to retrieve a DataTable in comparison to fixing your problem.